# MySQL replication - replicate only one database on slave? can I still perform the regular operation on other databases on slave?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-replication

I have an important mysql my_database hosted on server A and since its data is quite important, I have decided to setup a mysql replication and make server A master and my other server, server B slave.

I also have a few websites hosted on server B and all of them need mysql databases.

So my question is, if I setup the mysql replication and only replicate one database:

ie. by using: replicate-do-db=my_database

will this affect my other databases in server B? can I still do the basic mysql operations (insert, update, select delete) on my other databases in server B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not affect the other databases on server B.

Comment: I did a backup every night using rsync, but again, since the data is very important, I don't want to lose anything from this database

Comment: It does make sense, by replicating it you have a live backup of it. I currently do both, not necessarily for the same reasons though.